# Editing spacing of bullet points in abstract of the YAML portion of an R Markdown document?

Tags: r, latex, yaml, knitr, r-markdown

How do I get all these bullet points to line up in the abstract of my R Markdown document? I've tried so many permutations of spaces, tabs, newlines, etc., that my head is spinning. There has to be an easy way.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "Tuesday, June 16, 2015"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_section: true
abstract: | 
  * Foo
  * Bar
  * Baz
---

# My first section #

hello
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc introduces the `\tightlist` environment if you don't separate lists items with a space. When keeping a space between * you avoid this and simply get `\begin{itemize} ...`. In addition, the first line in  abstract is always indented in LATEX, it is the standard expected behaviour. Use `\noindent` to remove the indentation.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "Tuesday, June 16, 2015"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    toc: true
    number_section: true
abstract: | 
 \noindent

  * Foo

  * Bar

  * Baz

---
# My first section #

hello
```

[image]